# How to use Dependency Injection in DAO Tests with JUNIT?

Tags: spring, hibernate, dependency-injection, junit, dao

I'm working with Hibernate and Spring.
Mys DAOs are working in my application.
I need create the tests now, but I have a problem.

This is my class test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:applicationContext-test.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
public class MunicipioDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private MunicipioDAO municipioDAO;

    @Test
    public void testCount() {
        ...     
        municipioDAO.count();
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet() {
        ...   
        municipioDAO.get(1);
        ...
    }
```

**The testCount() works, but with testGet() I get this exception:**

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.eagle.eagleservice.model.entity.Municipio
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1192)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:2436)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2100(SessionImpl.java:172)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2378)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2382)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2369)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1052)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:967)
at com.eagle.core.model.dao.AbstractDAO.get(AbstractDAO.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy56.get(Unknown Source)
at com.eagle.eagleservice.model.dao.MunicipioDaoTest.testFind(MunicipioDaoTest.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

This is my `applicationContext-test.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:zksp="http://www.zkoss.org/2008/zkspring/core"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
    http://www.zkoss.org/2008/zkspring/core http://www.zkoss.org/2008/zkspring/core/zkspring-core.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.eagle.core, com.eagle.eagleservice" />

<!-- Enables ZK custom scopes for Spring Beans -->
<zksp:zk-config/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://servidor:5432/eagleservice_tu" />
    <property name="username" value="admin" />
    <property name="password" value="admin" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.eagle.core.model, com.eagle.eagleservice.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">auto</prop>

            <!-- Habilita a alteração do banco de dados automaticamente sempre que o mapeamento das entidades forem alteradas -->
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>            
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- A transaction manager for working with Hibernate SessionFactories -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="messageSource"   class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:org/springframework/security/messages"/>
</bean>
```

**What is wrong here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is operating correctly, the DAO is getting injected into the test.

The error `Unknown entity: com.eagle.eagleservice.model.entity.Municipio` is due to Hibernate is unable to find the Municipo class that the DAO is using.

Looks like the sessionFactory bean is not scanning the package `com.eagle.eagleservice.model.entity` that the `Municipio` entity is in.

In the sesionFactory bean, change

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.eagle.core.model, com.eagle.eagleservice.model" />
```

To include `com.eagle.eagleservice.model.entity`

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.eagle.core.model, com.eagle.eagleservice.model, com.eagle.eagleservice.model.entity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `packagesToScan` does not contain the package the entity class is in: `com.eagle.eagleservice.model.entity`.